# I can not boot ubuntu installation CD nor installation USB-drive with HP Envy DV6 notebook

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, secure-boot

Hello two weeks ago I uninstalled windows 10 and installed fedora 23 using a USB drive created by win32diskimager.

My notebook : HP Envy dv6
current OS : fedora 23

Fedora 23 have some bugs with my computer so I decided to give ubuntu a chance.

However I cannot boot from usb or CD/DVD for the installation.
I have make some research and changed the boot order
I have activated the legacy mode and deactivated the secure boot option but it still does not work.

I have not the option to boot from CD/DVD not from an USB drive in the <kbd>F9</kbd>-bootmenu

I have:

```
HDD EFI
BOOT FROM EFI FILES (In this menu my CD or USB is visible)
```

But I have already installed an OS (fedora 23) with a bootable usb drive on this pc but it doesn't work anymore.

Could you please help me? :)

ps : i'm french, sorry for the mistakes :).

Comment: How did you create the Live USB?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your USB flash drive was prepared incorrectly. There are several programs that can be used to create USB flash drives from `.iso` files, and they don't all work perfectly, especially for EFI-bootable systems. Based on posts I've seen, [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) seems to be the most reliable and [Pen Drive Linux/YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) is useless for creating EFI-mode disks. See [these comments of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#creating-media) for more details on my own experiences with several tools.

You could also try using the "BOOT FROM EFI FILES" option you mention. Once you select that option, you should see a primitive file selector. (Details vary from one EFI to another.) Browse to your boot medium and find the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file and launch it.

Comment: I used rufus for creating the usb
When i try the EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi an error display

Answer (score 0):

I guessing the fedora installation image on the  usb drive was an UEFI compatible image, the ubuntu one may not.

Try to find an option in the BIOS settings to boot legacy devices. It may called "legacy mode" or "CSM mode". Maybe there is an option to deactivate UEFI.

After enabling CSM or legacy mode or respectively disabling UEFI you should can boot the ubuntu installation media.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work, I can't see my media.
I have tried with a fedora 17 CD and it work but not with ubuntu

Comment: does the boot menu options change?

Comment: Yes some number are added after the line 
like HDD 56465464 EFI

Comment: And you USB drive is not shown? Did you try it at an other computer? Maybe the stick is not bootable?

Comment: The usb is not shown and I have try with my acer computer and it works with the acer

Comment: If you want i could post 2 photos of the bios conf and bios boot menu

Comment: If you need to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy support to boot a USB drive, then ***DON'T***! If the CSM is disabled, then that means that the currently-installed OS is almost certainly booting in EFI mode, and enabling the CSM runs the risk of creating a mixed-mode installation, which is a Bad Thing. If you want to *completely replace* the current OS, though, that's not so important.

Comment: I want to fully remove the current OS :)